# Graphics2D only, screen to user coordinates

Tags: java, awt

Being in an callback and having only `Graphics2D` as parameter, no access to the calling `Component`, how can I find back from the screen coordinates returned by `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` to the user coordinates I need to supply to the `Graphics2D` calls ?

Modifying the antediluvian calling library is not an option.

Tried `getDeviceConfiguration().getBounds()`, got `0,0,Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Tried `getDeviceConfiguration().getDefaultTransform()` and `getDeviceConfiguration().getNormalizingTransform()`, got identity transform